# Mount S3 bucket as an NFS share on an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

long time reader but I've usually been able to find the answers I've been looking for in existing posts - but this time I've not been able to.

I am essentially teaching myself AWS CDK from scratch, I've only really just started with it so not finding anything which helps me on my mission may be a result of not knowing enough yet to be asking the right questions... so please bare with me.

Thus far I've used the AWS CDK with Python to create a stack which creates an S3 bucket, and also fires up an EC2 instance with an AWS file storage gateway AMI loaded on it (so running Amazon Linux).  This deploys and runs fine - however now I'd like to programmatically set up the S3 bucket to be accessed via an NFS share on the EC2 instance.  From what I've seen I'd assumed it is or should be fairly trivial however I keep getting a bit lost in documentation and internet hunts and not quite sure I'm looking in the right places or asking search engines the right questions to unlock the path to achieve this.

It looks like I should be able to script something up to make it happen when the instance is start using user-data but I'm a bit lost.  Is anyone able to throw me some crumbs to follow to find a good way of achieving this, or a better way of achieving what I want to happen (which is basically accessing the S3 bucket contents as though they are files on an EC2 instance) - if not tell me how to do it if it's trivial enough?

Much appreciated :)
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You are on good track. [user_data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) can be used for that.

I don't have full code to give you as its use case specific (e.g. which OS are you using?), but the `user_data`  would have to download and install [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse):

> s3fs allows Linux and macOS to **mount an S3 bucket via FUSE**. s3fs preserves the native object format for files, allowing use of other tools like AWS CLI.

However, S3 is an **object storage system**, and it can't be really mounted on an instance like you would do with NFS or EBS storage solutions. But with `s3fs-fuse` you can mimic such a behavior. And for some use-cases it will be sufficient.

So what you can do, is to setup the user_data script through console, verify that it works, and then basically just copy and paste to CDK. Its more of a trial-and-see approach, but this is the best way to learn.

Comment: Thank you for your response, very helpful (I can't give the post feedback yet as I'm too much of a newb)

I have edited the original post to clarify that the EC2 instance runs Amazon Linux.  I'll have a play with what you've suggested and see if it seems like it's going to do what I'm after.

Cheers!

Comment: @MrZiltoid No problem. Let me know how it will go.